# How to get guest user sessionid in Yii2?

Tags: yii2, sessionid, yii2-advanced-app

I have used YII's session_id's to track user activity across a website with the following code snippet:

`Yii::app()->getSession()->getSessionId()`

How do I get same sessionid in Yii2? I tried quite possible way, but its all vain.

Please share the exact code snippet for Yii2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try with

```
Yii::$app->session->getId();
```

this guide could  be   useful to you  http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-sessions-cookies.html

try checking if a session is already active before and ifnot use session open() .

```
session = Yii::$app->session;

// check if a session is already open
if ($session->isActive) ...

// open a session
$session->open();

// close a session
$session->close();

// destroys all data registered to a session.
$session->destroy();
```

Comment: Hey, "Yii::$app->session->getId();" is returning an empty string. My expected output is hash_code (Example: eesa86vo3e74npmal76ds4dan4).

Answer (score 1):

```
$session = Yii::$app->session;

// if session is not open, open session
if ( !$session->isActive) { $session->open(); }

// get session id
Yii::$app->session->getId();
```

I got 26 character string in session id. "itddoa1lr247phpds34aemr0v0"

This link can be helpful: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-sessions-cookies.html#sessions

Answer (score 0):

`Yii::$app->session->Id`

And no need to explicitly open session. When you access session data through the session component, a session will be automatically opened if it has not been done so before. 
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-sessions-cookies.html#sessions